# Core Data exception: SQLite "no such column" error after adding a new attribute to an entity

Tags: core-data

After adding a String attribute called "localFilePath" to a Core Data entity called GenericAttachment, we started getting an exception when we try to map over a Set of those objects.

Several of our entities have a to-many relationship called "attachments" to an unordered collection of GenericAttachment.

One of these entities is called InspectionMO. GenericAttatchment has a to-many relationship "inspection" (not "inspections", oops) to InspectionMO. When we get an InspectionMO’s attachments and try to map over them, we get the following exception:

```
NSInternalInconsistencyException
I/O error for database at /Users/justingarcia/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D075B44C-4F54-4703-8817-3DC4A6E7314E/data/Containers/Data/Application/F425E5AC-C215-4BE8-93DB-A3E6C48C83C4/Library/Application Support/Procore/Procore.  SQLite error code:1, 'no such column: t1.Z_55ATTACHMENTS5'
```

Here is the exception stack trace:

```
#0  0x000000010c94f705 in objc_exception_throw ()
#1  0x000000010e928f00 in -[NSSQLiteConnection prepareSQLStatement:] ()
#2  0x000000010ea99305 in -[NSSQLiteConnection selectRowsWithStatement:cached:] ()
#3  0x000000010e941d0b in newFetchedRowsForFetchPlan_MT ()
#4  0x000000010eb6e574 in _newFetchedPKsForRelationshipFaultRequest ()
#5  0x000000010eb6efba in _executeNewValuesForRelationshipFaultRequest ()
#6  0x000000010ead19a2 in -[NSSQLRelationshipFaultRequestContext executeRequestCore:] ()
#7  0x000000010eb40a00 in -[NSSQLStoreRequestContext executeRequestUsingConnection:] ()
#8  0x000000010eb14e5b in __52-[NSSQLDefaultConnectionManager handleStoreRequest:]_block_invoke ()
#9  0x000000011b25f602 in _dispatch_client_callout ()
#10 0x000000011b26d653 in _dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete ()
#11 0x000000010eb14d40 in -[NSSQLDefaultConnectionManager handleStoreRequest:] ()
#12 0x000000010eb1cbb4 in -[NSSQLCoreDispatchManager routeStoreRequest:] ()
#13 0x000000010ea61515 in -[NSSQLCore dispatchRequest:withRetries:] ()
#14 0x000000010ea5cdaa in -[NSSQLCore _newValuesForRelationship:forObjectWithID:withContext:error:] ()
#15 0x000000010e97a8cb in -[NSSQLCore newValueForRelationship:forObjectWithID:withContext:error:] ()
#16 0x000000010ea449d9 in __110-[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(_NSInternalMethods) newValueForRelationship:forObjectWithID:withContext:error:]_block_invoke ()
#17 0x000000010ea39437 in -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator _routeLightweightBlock:toStore:] ()
#18 0x000000010e97a7f7 in -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(_NSInternalMethods) newValueForRelationship:forObjectWithID:withContext:error:] ()
#19 0x000000010ea0b89e in __107-[NSManagedObjectContext(_NestedContextSupport) newValueForRelationship:forObjectWithID:withContext:error:]_block_invoke ()
#20 0x000000010e972108 in internalBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform ()
#21 0x000000011b25f602 in _dispatch_client_callout ()
#22 0x000000011b26d653 in _dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete ()
#23 0x000000010e972074 in _perform ()
#24 0x000000010e972c37 in -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NestedContextSupport) newValueForRelationship:forObjectWithID:withContext:error:] ()
#25 0x000000010e97a421 in -[NSFaultHandler retainedFulfillAggregateFaultForObject:andRelationship:withContext:] ()
#26 0x000000010e9a621e in -[_NSFaultingMutableSet willReadWithContents:] ()
#27 0x000000010e94e6a6 in -[_NSFaultingMutableSet count] ()
#28 0x000000011a9e9bdd in protocol witness for Collection.count.getter in conformance Set<A> ()
#29 0x000000011a8726d1 in Collection.map<A>(_:) ()
#30 0x00000001162ad07e in ObjectImportHelper.copyToMany<A>(_:to:cache:deleteMissing:onCopy:) at /Users/justingarcia/2/iOS/Procore/Core/Utils/ObjectImportHelper+Relationships.swift:163
…
```

And here is some of the Core Data logging:

```
CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK FROM Z_55INSPECTION t1 JOIN ZGENERICATTACHMENT t0 ON t0.Z_PK = t1.Z_55ATTACHMENTS5 WHERE t1.Z_70INSPECTION = ? 
2019-01-25 13:50:17.727987-0800 Procore[34877:10124838] [logging] no such column: t1.Z_55ATTACHMENTS5
CoreData: annotation: Disconnecting from sqlite database due to an error.
2019-01-25 13:50:17.748021-0800 Procore[34877:10124838] [error] error: (1) I/O error for database at /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/FFEB392B-302B-479E-98E8-008333FC2714/Library/Application Support/Procore/Procore.  SQLite error code:1, 'no such column: t1.Z_55ATTACHMENTS5'
CoreData: error: (1) I/O error for database at /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/FFEB392B-302B-479E-98E8-008333FC2714/Library/Application Support/Procore/Procore.  SQLite error code:1, 'no such column: t1.Z_55ATTACHMENTS5'
CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0207s for 0 rows.
2019-01-25 13:50:17.748727-0800 Procore[34877:10124838] [error] error: exception during newFetchedPKsForSourceID: I/O error for database at /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/FFEB392B-302B-479E-98E8-008333FC2714/Library/Application Support/Procore/Procore.  SQLite error code:1, 'no such column: t1.Z_55ATTACHMENTS5' with userInfo of {
    NSFilePath = "/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/FFEB392B-302B-479E-98E8-008333FC2714/Library/Application Support/Procore/Procore";
    NSSQLiteErrorDomain = 1;
}
```

We are using NSPersistentStoreDescription’s shouldMigrateStoreAutomatically and shouldInferMappingModelAutomatically and I’m not seeing any migration errors in the logs (we are using -com.apple.CoreData.MigrationDebug 1).

We opened up the SQLite database file and found that the Z_55INSPECTION table has a column named Z_55ATTACHMENTS6 (not Z_55ATTACHMENTS5) both before and after the migration to this new version where we added the localFilePath attribute to GenericAttachment.

So why is Core Data looking for a column named Z_55ATTACHMENTS5 instead of Z_55ATTACHMENTS6?

We found these two Apple mailing list articles after Googling around: [a question](https://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2011/Jul/msg00629.html) and [this follow-up](https://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2011/Jul/msg00663.html) which I think are saying that the number at the end of the column name appears when multiple entities have to-many relationships of the same name to another entity. In our case we have several many-to-many relationships called attachments to GenericAttachment. But we didn’t add a new relationship called attachments, we just added an attribute to GenericAttachment. Maybe if we rename all of these relationships to be unique the problem will go away?

Comment: Can you test the same thing doesn't happen on other entities which have dependencies on the GenericAttachment? If yes, there should be something wrong with your setup.

Answer (score 0):

it selects that column, because the query refers to `Z_55INSPECTION.Z_55ATTACHMENTS5`:

```
SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK FROM Z_55INSPECTION t1

JOIN ZGENERICATTACHMENT t0 ON t0.Z_PK = t1.Z_55ATTACHMENTS5

WHERE t1.Z_70INSPECTION = ?
```

the most easy might be to  rename that column from `Z_55ATTACHMENTS6` to `Z_55ATTACHMENTS5`

... keep a backup of the database, just to be sure nothing else refers to it.